# PDF reader for Linux which renders like Foxit reader (not Chrome or Firefox)

Tags: pdf, software-rec

I use [Foxit Reader](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf-reader/) as my default pdf reader in Windows 10. I've seen that it renders text slightly blacker/bolder than other readers such as Adobe Acrobat, Okular, Evince, Zathura, MuPDF. I like this rendering for thin fonts such as Computer Modern. I use Okular in Manjaro.

What are alternative pdf readers which render like Foxit on Linux? I know there is Foxit reader for Linux as well but I find it hard to use as it has fewer features (mostly keyboard shortcuts) compared to the Windows version. Chrome and Firefox inbuilt readers render different than Okular but I find their text to be blurry. My screen resolution is 1920 × 1080 and screen size is 15.6 inches diagonally, i.e. approximately 19940.83 pixels per sq. inch if that makes any difference.

Or is there some setting which I can change to make text appear blacker in Okular/other viewers?

Comparison images —

In Okular:
[image: okular]

In Foxit:
[image: foxit]

Comment: Your Foxit sample seems to use [sub-pixel rendering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering) while the Okular one doesn't. You can enable sub-pixel rendering in Linux.

Comment: @xenoid Sub-pixel rendering (RGB) is already enabled. Font DPI is set to 120.

Comment: @xenoid Also, I see the differences in Windows too where ClearType is enabled.

Comment: "ClearType" in Microsoft's name for SPR.